# Isn't the axiom of determinacy inconsistent with ZF? What am I overlooking?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm sure there's something I'm missing here; probably a naive confusion of mathematics with metamathematics. Regardless, I've come up with what looks to me like a proof that (first-order) ZF+AD is inconsistent:

Assume otherwise. Then it cannot be shown that ZF+AD is consistent relative to ZF. However, ZFC is consistent relative to ZF, and as ZF+AD is consistent (by our assumption for contradiction,) a model of ZF+AD exists in ZFC by Gödel's completeness theorem. Hence ZF+AD is consistent relative to ZFC. This establishes that ZF+AD is consistent relative to ZF, a contradiction.

I'd appreciate anyone pointing out the problematic step(s).

EDIT: Upon further thought, under the (misguided) assumption that this argument holds, an adaption of this argument can be used to show that every first-order countable theory has a countable model in ZF: ZFC has a model in ZF (I think this was shown by Cohen via forcing?) and such a theory has a model in ZFC by the first incompleteness theorem. "Composing" these models gives us a model of the theory in ZF.

Comment: I asked what looks like a similar question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344825/axiom-of-choice-and-determinacy

Comment: One obvious problem with your argument: there's nothing specific to AD about it.  If it were correct, you could show that ZF$\implies$ ZFC, which of course is known to not be true.  But more specifically: just because there's a model of a theory $T$ in ZFC doesn't mean that the _model_ (internally) satisfies choice.  A choice function may exist for sets in the model but not be part of the model itself.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm completely misinterpreting things here, as I try to use a deductivist philosophy when talking about axiom systems. The only thing specific about AD being used here is that AD implies the consistency of ZF, and so any proof of ZF+AD's consistency relative to ZF would imply ZF is inconsistent by the second incompleteness theorem. And no, of course the model of ZF+AD wouldn't necessarily satisfy choice. I apologize if I'm being extremely thick-headed.

Comment: @BatDejean Consistency of ZF+AD is not a theorem of ZFC. It requires some kind of large cardinal axiom and assuming a large cardinal makes its consistency strength greater. (in fact, ZFC + 'there is some large cardinal' proves the consistency of ZFC.)

Comment: (Add: Consistency of ZF+AD is not provable even if assuming Con(ZFC), Con(ZFC+Con(ZFC)) , etc since existence of inaccessible cardinal proves former statementes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is problematic. You claim that the theory is inconsistent. Okay. So by contradiction it is not inconsistent, therefore the working assumption is that the theory is consistent.

But a theory being consistent does not mean consistent relative to $\sf ZF$. it means consistent. Moreover the fact there is a model of $T$ in a universe of $T'$ is not a contradiction. It's a set model, it's a toy model. It's not saying what is true or false in the universe. Finally, you conclude that there is a model which is a contradiction, but the working assumption towards contradiction was that there is a model in the first place!

For the second part, forcing cannot increase the consistency strength. This means that it cannot generate models out of nowhere without additional assumptions. In particular forcing requires us to assume the consistency of $\sf ZFC$, rather than proving it. And since we already assume there are models of $\sf ZFC$ nothing wrong in using them.

I'd just like to add that the completeness theorem does require some choice to be proved, but for countable theories it can be avoided.

Comment: Thanks. If it's fine, I'll ask for a few clarifications.

Firstly, it's possible I'm being rather thick, but the existence of such a model would be a contradiction due to the fact that AD implies Con(ZF); that is, Con(ZF) is a theorem of ZF+AD. Hence Con(ZFC) is a theorem of ZF+AD, so a model of ZF+AD in ZFC would mean ZFC would be inconsistent by the second incompleteness theorem. Thus ZF would be inconsistent, so ZF+AD would be inconsistent; this is the contradiction I was mentioning. If this step's invalid, please explain in greater detail. (...)

Comment: No, a model of $\sf ZFC$ just means that you're working in a theory which is *stronger* than $\sf ZFC$. You could apply this to $\sf PA$. Since $\sf ZFC$ proves the consistency of $\sf PA$, but $\sf PA$ doesn't, does that mean that $\sf ZFC$ is inconsistent just because it proves more than $\sf PA$?

Comment: (...) I don't quite follow your next statement; my understanding of the forcing results is that they establish that ZF and ZFC have the same consistency strength. Then ZF+AD proves the consistency of ZF, so it proves the consistency of ZFC. I'm effectively just using Con(ZF)↔Con(ZFC).

Again, please clarify if any of this doesn't work; I'm just not quite understanding my mistake.

I'm effectively getting from your and Sam's answers that the most problematic step is a naive confusion of mathematics with metamathematics in my claim that a model of ZF+AD exists in ZFC; metamathematically (...)

Comment: The issue with forcing is that it is not used to ***prove*** that there is a model of $\sf ZFC$. Forcing begins with the assumption that there is a model of $\sf ZFC$, and then we construct *other* models of $\sf ZFC$, and so we prove that $\sf ZFC$ cannot possibly prove or disprove certain statement (unless it was inconsistent). Your question claimed that forcing is used to prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ in $\sf ZF$, which is not true.

Comment: (Intermission to reply to your comment: wouldn't that only imply that we're working in a theory at least stronger than ZFC? NBG's equiconsistent with ZFC, and NBG models ZFC.)

EDIT: Another comment to read. Evidently my understanding of the forcing results was flawed; thanks.

Comment: No, $\sf NBG$ does not prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC$. Not to mention that the completeness theorem only applies to *set* models, not class models.

Comment: Huh. I've run into the claim that ZFC and NBG are equiconsistent, providing a model of one equiconsistent theory in another.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Which means that $\sf ZFC$ cannot prove that $\sf NBG$ has a model, or vice versa.

Comment: So it would seem my reasoning breaks down here due to another naive confusion of mathematics with metamathematics(?) Good to know.

Comment: It's not very difficult, but it is very delicate. I can tell you that it took me more than just my M.Sc. to get all these things in order in my head. And my thesis used forcing extensively. I will point out again, that everything falls apart on the first line. When you assume that $\sf ZF+AD$ is ***not*** inconsistent, you were ultimately saying that you're working in a very strong meta-theory, much stronger than just $\sf ZFC$.

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of your second paragraph, you assume the statement $Con(ZF+AD)$ and then get a set model of $ZF+AD$ by Gödel's completeness theorem (in $ZFC$ or $ZF$, as our meta theory). Then, you claim that $ZF+AD$ is consistent relative to $ZFC$. Why would the statement $Con(ZFC) \rightarrow Con(ZF+AD)$ follow? Your assumption to get the model of $ZF+AD$ was the statement $Con(ZF+AD)$ itself and it does not follow from $Con(ZFC)$ alone.

Answer (score 0):

What Asaf Karagila says in the second paragraph of his answer is basically what you are overlooking in your argument. Namely, it is implied in your argument that the statement $''\text{Con}(ZF+AD)\implies ZFC\vdash\text{Con}(ZF+AD)''$ is true in the meta-theory. But this is not necessarily true. What is true in the meta-theory is that $''\varphi\implies ZFC\vdash\varphi''$ whenever $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence. However, since $\text{Con}(ZF+AD)$ is a $\Pi_1$ sentence, then this fact doesn't apply. (By ''true'' I actually mean ''meta-theorem'' ).

So your conclusion that "a model of $ZF+AD$ exists in $ZFC$ by Gödel's completeness theorem" must actually be rephrased to "a model of $ZF+AD$ exists in $ZFC+\text{Con}(ZF+AD)$ by Gödel's completeness theorem". But this fact (along with the other facts you are using) isn't enough to establish the contradiction you are looking for.

Also, the method of forcing does not produce a set model for (all of) $ZFC$ from within $ZFC$. So we are not justified in inferring $''ZFC\vdash\text{Con}(ZFC)''$ by appealing solely to forcing results and Gödel's completeness theorem. ​